# How to force powersave to a slower CPU speed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, power-management, fan

I have a system76 laptop running ubuntu 16.04 the fan constantly comes on unless it's on **powersave mode** and the cpu MHZ is running around 1000hz.  The issue is the powersave mode doesn't always take effect.  How can I force the powersave mode to go to a certain speed or really do what it's suppose to do and lower the cpu speed more?

When I do a **lscpu**.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3303.375
CPU max MHz:           3400.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4789.12
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

when I do **cpufreq-info**

```
$ cpufreq-info 
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.39 GHz.
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.39 GHz.
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.41 GHz.
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.37 GHz.
analyzing CPU 4:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 4
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 4
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.40 GHz.
analyzing CPU 5:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 5
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 5
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.97 GHz.
analyzing CPU 6:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 6
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 6
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.40 GHz.
analyzing CPU 7:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 7
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.31 GHz.
```